# how to delete a node programitically in drupal 6?

Tags: 6, users

I want to add delete permission for a specific node id programitically. I try calling 'node_delete' but it doesn't work.

how can I do it ?

Comment: can you explain what "doesnt work" means?

Answer (score 1):

The node_delete() function requires to have the delete permission for the current logged user.
If you run the node_delete() function as anon user, is probably that doesn't work

Comment: So what is the solution in this case?

Comment: @hd. Can you explain your scenario ?